# Eclipse UI unusable. No icons, unresponsive buttons, no text editor

Tags: java, eclipse, archlinux, modelio

I've been having problems recently with Eclipse on Arch Linux. It started earlier this week when some functionalities stopped working and would result in an error report (e.g. creating a new project, java or otherwise). I tried uninstalling eclipse-common and eclipse-java packages and reinstalling, and running `yaourt -Syua`, also didn't work. I forgot about it since I had other stuff to do that didn't require eclipse, but today I had to use it again and the UI was completely unusable. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Eclipse UI]

Running `eclipse -clean` didn't help. The error log is over 10500 lines long so I don't know where to upload it... Most errors have to do with Modelio though. Example:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-04-22 16:00:12.390
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.app.ui/icons/save.png".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.app.ui/icons/save.png".
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-22 16:00:12.391
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.modelio.app.ui/icons/save.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.app.ui/icons/save.png".
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-22 16:00:12.395
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.modelio.app.ui/icons/undo.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.app.ui/icons/undo.png".
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-22 16:00:13.658
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.modelio.edition.notes/icons/description_note.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.edition.notes/icons/description_note.png".
...
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2016-04-22 16:00:13.659
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.edition.notes/icons/description_note.png".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.modelio.edition.notes/icons/description_note.png".
```

EDIT: I clicked post to soon. I removed Modelio but the problem persists.

Comment: Unzip a fresh Eclipse to a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your ~/.eclipse and ~/.modelio directories then try again.